# Do I need to enable a Service Broker endpoint on SQL 2005 to use SQLCacheDependency?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, caching

My question really has three related parts which I hope you can help me clear up -

1. Do I need to enable a Service Broker endpoint on SQL 2005 to use the SQLCacheDependency mechanism?
2. If so, is there a specific port that needs to be used?
3. If neither of the web server machine and sql server are in a domain, what type of authentication is required, if at all? Certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need enable a service broker endpoint to use the SQLCacheDependency.  A Service Broker Endpoint is only used to send SQL Service Broker messages from one instance to another.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Are there any gotcha's you can think of? Will this work ok with just SQL server authentication rather than windows auth? And finally is it sufficient for the user to be just DBO in the DB concerned or are any other rights required?